# Select sum or updating a field for Total Balance?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, database-design, azure-sql-database

I'm using Entity Framework and Azure Sql.

I have users and they have records on balance table.Some of users may have 1 million record.I need total balance of the user before every http requests.

I have two approaches for getting total balance of user:

First:
Insert balance and update totalbalance field (by itself) in a transaction.

```
transaction(
InsertBalance(amount)
Update CustomerSummary Set Totalbalance=Totalbalance+Amount
)
```

If I need total balance I'll just select this from `CustomerSummary` table.

Second: Inserts balance directly without using any transaction.
If I need total balance I have to get sum by query.

Is the first approach reliable for total balance ?

Can I get sum on second approach as fast as like first approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second approach is guaranteed to be accurate -- if you want the sum of a particular column, there is nothing more accurate than a query that calculates the sum.

The reason for maintaining a summary table is performance.  Typically, such a table is maintained in one of two ways:

- Triggers
- Stored procedures that wrap *all* data modification operations

Your example with the `insert` is an "application-side" solution.  The danger is that someone might come along and say that a balance is incorrect and then have the value changed directly in the database.  The total doesn't get changed.

To make this work correctly, you need to have the right controls over access to the database to ensure that whenever `amount` changes, then all its dependencies change.  Note:  this is not an issue if you calculate the balance when you need it.